# Global variable declariation in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have couple of controller where I declare perpage variable for pagination as follows:

```
   // per page definition 
   protected $perpage = 10;
```

How can I make this variable global for all my controllers? instead of having the same declaration on every controller

Thanks

Comment: You could use it as a configuration setting. Check http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: do I put it in my own file? or I choose a file drom the config/ folder , like app.php?

Comment: I create one for my own settings. But is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) says, you can create a configuration file on the app/config directory, lets name it app_globals, it can contains the above:

```
<?php

return array(

    'perpage' => 10,

);
```

And you can access it everywhere like this:

```
Config::get('app_globals.perpage');
```

Also you can use the inheritance approach, i.e declare the property on a BaseController class and then inherit from this class:

```
class BaseGlobalController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     */
   private $per_page = 10

}
```

and then

```
class XController extends BaseGlobalController {

}
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Use your own file for custom configuration. You may try something like this:

```
$perpage = Config::get('settings.pagination.perpage')
```

Now just create a `settings.php` file in the `app/config` folder with this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'pagination' => array('perpage' => 10)
);
```

You can also use a single (one dimensional) array like this:

```
$perpage = Config::get('settings.pagination');
```

So the array should be:

```
return array( 'pagination' => 10 );
```

So when using pagination in any controller you may use something like this:

```
$allUsers = User::paginate(Config::get('settings.pagination'));
```

Comment: This works as well , you can also put it in the config/app.php and add it there

Comment: It's not a problem but I don't change anything original instead I extend from them.

Comment: oh I see your point , so its better to create a file config/settings.php and put your own better

Comment: You got it @user3150060 :-)